# Apply for a Bulgaria visa in Canada

Tags: visas, bulgaria

How do we apply for a Bulgaria visa in Canada?

According to [the website](https://www.mfa.bg/en/pages/109/index.html), it looks like there are no **VISA APPLICATION CENTERS (OUTSOURCING CENTERS)** in Canada.

These are all the application centers listed on the website:

- RUSSIA
- UKRAINE
- UNITED ARAB EMIRATES
- QATAR
- OMAN
- BAHRAIN
- SAUDI ARABIA
- TURKEY
- KAZAHSTAN

Then it seems that we have to use the service provided by [VFS Global](http://www.vfsglobal.com/) according to that webpage. However, from the VFS Global website, the only thing that I can find is this at the bottom:

[image]

And Canada is not in the list. What do we do?

Comment: What citizenship do you have?

Comment: @NRandhawa Chinese. Does that make any difference?

Comment: Yes, @Yuchen Zhong What kind of canadien visa do you have?

Comment: @NRandhawa It is permanent resident status. So no VISA needed in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Bulgaria college of mine got in touch with foreign ministry in Bulgaria and confirmed that we do need a visa to visit Bulgaria. PR status doesn't help.

However, having any visa from any Schengen country is enough for entering Bulgaria.

Answer (score 1):

Edited: Yes, you need a Visa.

Source  @Yuchen Zhong (OP): A Bulgaria college of mine got in touch with foreign ministry in Bulgaria and confirmed that we do need a visa to visit Bulgaria. PR status doesn't help.

**Not True:**
Bulgaria tourist visa is not required for citizens of China living in Canada for a stay up to 90 days. https://bulgaria.visahq.ca/requirements/china/resident-canada/

Comment: You're quoting an private website that gives wrong information. Bulgaria uses the same list of visa-exempt nationality as the Schengen states, and China is _not_ on that list.

Comment: I have edited the information. Tnx

Comment: It's a bit confusing what you're saying is true and what you're saying is false. It's perfectly acceptable to simply delete information you have determined is wrong. If you want to keep it in your answer, you might want to use <s> to strikeout the text.

Comment: I have changed it!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not in one of the listed countries where Bulgaria uses outsourcing centers to receive visa applications, you must file your application directly with the Bulgarian embassy or consulate.